# Jupyter notebook doesn't find module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a directory called "auth" inside the root directory. In my **main** script I need to access another script called *client.py*, which is in the auth folder.

For this I'm running the following command:

```
from auth.client import Test
```

When running the main script in the terminal, it works. But using the Jupyter notebook extension for VSCode, it returns the following error:

```
    >>> from auth.client import Test
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'auth.client'
```

I have no idea how to solve this, anyone can help?

Comment: did you add an __init_.py file?  And what directory are you executing your script from?

Comment: In jupyter, would you verify you're in the right directory by using `%pwd`?

Comment: @EhabIbrahim it looks like I wasn't in the right directory, but I dont know how to navegate to my project directory with jupyter

Comment: You can use `%cd`